# Deploy ASP.NET Core 7 solution with three projects

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, publish, self-hosting

I'm new to Blazor server development and seem to be having issues in deploying this. How do I publish and host my ASP.NET Core 7 Blazor server application that has 3 projects to IIS? Is there any difference between this kind of solution compared to the just one solution (one project) deployment?

I also have a Web API which appears to of been deployed fine.

Through VS Professional, locally everything works fine. After I publish the application from VS Pro 2022 on my local dev machine, I copy it to the hosting server adding it to IIS. Same with the Web API. Both have there own application pools (managed code?).

If I run the Web API, locally on the hosting server (prefixing the URL with Swagger) it works. If I run the application with the three projects, it doesn't work.

The folders all have `IIS_USERS` permissions and the server has the Core Module/Hosting Bundle installed.

Now on my dev machine accessing the server the Web API seems to be fine (`http://servername:port/swagger`). However when I run the application (`http://servername:port`) with three projects I get

> This page isn't working right now

and I a HTTP ERROR 500.

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Do you want to deploy three different projects under the same solution under the same site in IIS? If so, then you need to reference the other two projects in one of the projects, and then deploy this project in IIS. Here is an [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced?view=aspnetcore-7.0#virtual-directories).

Comment: If not, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have three different projects under the same solution. The web api is an entirely separate solution which I don't think it's even accessing because of this issue. All thre projects have dependencies on one another. For example:  StaffReporting (this is the solution) with a Business project, Data project, and StaffReporting project (wwwroot, Pages, Shared etc...). We use windows authentication, so our app.razor page has the <cascadingAuthenticationState><AuthorizeRouteView> tags and the program.cs has 
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)  .AddNegotiate

Comment: I just ran : application.exe dotnet.exe and saw the following error appear : Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
"DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.AuthenticationScheme: Negotiate was challenged.Incomplete Negotiate handshake, sending an additional 401 Negotiate challenge. "

Comment: Have you enabled anonymous access to see if you can access it?